# Magento 2 API, searchCriteria usage on orders

Tags: orders, rest-api, search-criteria

I'm trying to retrieve recent orders from Magento 2.3.5, via REST API. I use this command:

```
curl -X GET "https://my_magento_site/index.php/rest/V1/orders/search?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2021-01-01&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gt" -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "Content-type: application/json" -g -o C:\orders.json
```

What I get is this error in my orders.json:

```
{"message":"The \"search\" value's type is invalid. The \"int\" type was expected. Verify and try again."}
```

I'm pretty sure REST API is working fine and authentication is OK. If I simply replace "orders" with "customers" in the above command, I get all recently added customers. Also issuing:

```
curl -X GET "https://my_magento_site/index.php/rest/V1/orders/1" -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "Content-type: application/json" -g -o C:\orders.json
```

returns my order "1" details.

What may be the problem ?

Comment: Did you check Magento core file where this error generated? Try to debug there, something may missing

Comment: I've no access to filesystem. Magento is hosted by a third party. I only have an admin access to console. What should I check from there ? Can't see any special thing related to API, apart Integration token generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself, hoping this can help someone else.

I investigated further and found that removing the "/search" part from the URI, solves the problem. This is the working curl command:

```
curl -X GET "https://my_magento_site/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2021-01-01&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gt" -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "Content-type: application/json" -g -o C:\orders.json
```

Note the "/orders?searchCriteria" instead of "/orders/search?searchCriteria"

The strange thing is that, if I query customers, the "/search" is mandatory (without it I receive an error). So my experience is I have to use "/search" for customers and not for orders. Haven't tried other collections by now.